# category url rewrite to cms page or other link Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

i have created a category named blog which has url key `blog.html` to appear on main menu.
And now i have a blog page at `<site-url>/blog`

I want to redirect blog.html [Category URL] to /blog

What i tried :

1. via url rewrite [Backend > Marketing > URL Rewrites]. Here blog.html is redirected to `catalog/category/view/id/5`.
   [image]

   - My intenstion was to create a url rewrite blog.html to /blog.
   - now when i try to create such redirect(custom type) it says "Request Path for Specified Store already exists."
   - I stuck here and couldn't create the desired redirect. 
     [image]
2. Then i tried with htaccess
   Inside `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` i added `Redirect 301 /blog.html http://www.mysiteurl.com/blog` where `RewriteEngine is on`

and didn't get the luck either way.

Answer (score 1):

Please only use `.htaccess` or https://github.com/Mestrona/Mestrona_CategoryRedirect Module. I already faced this issue.

1. Delete & Create that Category Again.
2. Use Above Module.
3. Lastly, i have solved by `.htaccess`.

Let me know if any issue.